# Rgb color effect in a label text, tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I was just experimenting with some code, I am trying to change the color of text inside a label(like the rgb color effect in physical keyboards), with the following code I did get the color to change, but what I am trying to achieve is getting the colors of each letter of the text to change, but I have no idea how to do that.

below is the code I have written :

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import random

color_list = ["red","blue","green","cyan1","yellow","purple"]



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")


i=0

txt = "Hello world"

l1 = tk.Label(root, text=txt)
l1.pack(pady=10)



def text():
   #global i 
   global l1
   global root
   global color_list
   global txt
   try:
      while True:
        #for j in range(0,len(txt)):
        random_value = random.randint(0,5)
        l1.config(fg=f"{color_list[random_value]}")
        l1.update()
        time.sleep(1)

    '''if i == 100:
        l1.config(text="Process completed")
        time.sleep(5)
        root.destroy()'''
      print()

except:
    print("Program Exited")

root.after(3000, lambda: text())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't do this with a label. The simplest way for a certain word would be to use pil and draw a picture of text. Another way with more effort could be the Text widget or to use a canvas.

Comment: I tried with canvas before, but it really doesn't let me configure the foreground of text. I will try with Pillow though, thanks for the information!

Comment: As Atlas435 suggested, you could use a `tkinter.Text` to make a multi-colored label. If you want it so that it can't be typed in, you could use `Text.config(state="disabled")`, and set the colors using tags. `Text` also has more formatting options than `Label`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: If you want more options, then create a frame(which will be your entire alphabet), then put each of these letters individually onto a frame, gridding it on the same row. Then you can manually give them a color

Comment: @CoolCloud Could you explain a bit more? I didn't quite understand you.

Comment: @SamMatzko I tried that, but the result is the same as that it was. The entire text color is getting changed at the same time....

Comment: @bruce_wayne224: Did you use tags, and assign them correctly? Try searching `[python] [tkinter] Text tags not working` on Stack Overflow. Maybe, if you search and research, and still can't find the answer, you should ask a question about the specific problem you had, and post your code, so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, using `Text` is one approach, but I feel using a `Frame`, is a more similar approach to what you have done. The basic idea is to create a main frame which will be like the entire sentence/word, then create each letter as individual labels, and change its color. You should not use `while` because it will interfere with the `mainloop` causing the application to freeze.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
color_list = ["red","blue","green","cyan1","yellow","purple"]
text = 'Hello World'

def change():
     for wid in alpha.winfo_children(): # Each letter 
          rand = random.randint(0,len(color_list)-1) # Get a random color
          wid.configure(fg=color_list[rand]) # Change the letter to that random color
     
     root.after(50,change) # Repeat every 50 millisecond

alpha = tk.Frame(root)
alpha.pack()

count = 0
for idx,letter in enumerate(text):
     tk.Label(alpha,text=letter,fg=color_list[count],font=(0,21)).grid(row=0,column=idx)
     if count < len(color_list)-1: 
          count += 1
     else:
          count = 0

change()
root.mainloop()
```

Most of the code is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Looks cool! Just a note: using wildcard imports is discouraged.

Comment: @SamMatzko Yea I realize that, but while answering I tend to use this usually(just out of practice), I expect the OP to already know this and use a proper way in their original code, but feel free to change this.

Comment: Looking at your edit, I suppose using `import tkinter as tk` is better, because, while it's not a wildcard import, it still saves time typing as opposed to simply `import tkinter`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks, it worked, however the color change is too fast, so maybe i can slow it down using time.sleep() ?

Comment: @bruce_wayne224 `root.after(50,change)`, adjust the time(50) to make it suit your needs