# Color some text in a Tkinter Label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, colors, label

I wanna color just an * in red on a Tkinter label, to indicate that that field is required. I have tried the following:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style

colorama.init()
date_label = Label(my_frame, text=f"Date: {Fore.RED} * {Style.RESET_ALL})"
date_label.pack()
```

And this is the output:

```
Date: [][31m*
```

I know that you can color a label with fg, but i wanna try just coloring the asterisk.

I have also tried the ANSI codes ans it gives the same output.

I'm on Windows btw.

Comment: While I don't remember how to do that for a Label, I do remember that you can format text regions in the Text widget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rgb color effect in a label text, tkinter python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69366657/rgb-color-effect-in-a-label-text-tkinter-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try combining 2 Label in different color:

```
from tkinter import *

Root = Tk()

Date = Label(Root, text="Date: ", fg="black")
Asterick = Label(Root, text="*", fg="red")
Date.grid(row=0, column=0)
Asterick.grid(row=0, column=1)
Root.mainloop()
```

*No need for colorama

Comment: I mean, if there's no other solution i will do it like that, but that will color all the text, and I just want the asterisk character.

Comment: Can you split text in to 2 labels? Such as make both in same 1 line. I'll try to correct my mistake.

Comment: Edited Now. You can try the code.

Comment: I'll do it like that, i see no other solution.